# Replicate a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

I'm to trying to adapt the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880248/precise-and-smooth-curve-with-tikz?fbclid=IwAR09VVJs9oYgp96-kg-Iq1EEfa5rBnm30zHFQp_YXcZJg4sTT0rzk7X20hI) to replicate the following image.

[image]

While I can do the axis and the labeling I cannot produce the curve. I do not understand what exactly the code does. Could someome help me? This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
%draw axes and label
\draw[->] (-4.5, 0) -- (4.5, 0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \i in {-4, -3 , ..., -1, 1, 2, ...,   4}
{
    \draw (\i, 0) node[above]{$\i$};   
}
\foreach \m in {-2, -1 , 1,2}
{
    \draw (0, \m) node[left]{$\m$}; 
} 
\draw (-0.2, 0) node[above]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (-2, 0) -- (-2, -1) -- (2, -1) -- (2, 0);
\draw[fill=black] (-2, -1) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2, -1) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (-1,0) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,0) circle(2pt);
draw[fill=black] (0, 2) circle(2pt);

\draw[thick, smooth] plot coordinates 
{
    (-4, -0.1)
    (-2, -1)
    (-1, 0)
    (0, 2)
    (1, 0)
    (2, -1)
    (4, -0.1)
};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I have only drawn the axes and the labels. I don't know how to proceed with the curve.

**Update:** I was able to draw the curve (somewhat). It's not perfect but I'll go with it at the moment. If anyone has a better idea, please share!

Comment: The code uses the `\addplot` command from pgfplots by constructing a curve that passes through the specified points. You use TikZ without drawing a curve.

Comment: I’ve seen that . But I don’t understand how that controls work , let alone the gradients .

Comment: The control points are defined in the Béziers curves. Read section 2.4 of the `Tutorial: A Picture for Karl's Students` of the [TikZ-PGF](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual.

Comment: How do you describe the curve?

Comment: What do you mean by “describe”?

Comment: I hate Karl and his students. There is a better way. Have a look at `PGFPlot`. It draw axis, scale, grid, ticks and more automatically and off cause it can plot a function.

Comment: I also hate the tutorial because Karl and his students are mentioned too often than necessary.

Comment: @Tolaso by "describe" I mean either the analytic expression of the curve, or just a random curve that look like the curve in the post. It will lead to different way of drawing

Comment: @BlackMild If I had a formula to describe the curve, I would have just plotted that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,plotpoints=500](-5,-1.5)(5.5,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-5,-1.5)(5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-4.5}{4.5}{-512*(x^2-1)/(27*x^6-168*x^4+560*x^2+256)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The remaining trivial decorations are intentionally left as your exercises.

Comment: I can do the following thanks.

Comment: +1 also for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer but an explanation of how it has to be done

In simple terms the answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880248/precise-and-smooth-curve-with-tikz?fbclid=IwAR09VVJs9oYgp96-kg-Iq1EEfa5rBnm30zHFQp_YXcZJg4sTT0rzk7X20hI -- pushes in additional coordinates/ points for fine `control`

Implementing the same in your answer will lead to

```
\draw[blue,line width=2pt,smooth] 
{(-4,-0.1)
(-4,-0.1)   ..controls(-3.6,-0.1) and (-2.9,-0.3)..
(-2.8,-0.5) ..controls(-2.5,-.9)  and (-2,-1)    ..
(-2,-1)

(2, -1)     ..controls(2.5,-0.9) and (2.8,-0.5) ..
(2.9,-0.3) ..controls(3.5,-0.1) and (4,-0.1) ..
(4,-0.1)
};
```

The code of controls has a set format/ syntax

```
{start point ..controls() and()..
next point ..controls() and()..
end point};
```

Pushing in these additional points results in a revised curve as under

[image]

For better clarity of the change I have commented out the major plot points which will be as under

[image]

After deleting the left and right side points which are no longer required we get the final curve

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
%draw axes and label
\draw[->] (-4.5, 0) -- (4.5, 0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \i in {-4, -3 , ..., -1, 1, 2, ...,   4}
{
    \draw (\i, 0) node[above]{$\i$};   
}
\foreach \m in {-2, -1 , 1,2}
{
    \draw (0, \m) node[left]{$\m$}; 
} 
\draw (-0.2, 0) node[above]{$0$};
\draw[dashed] (-2, 0) -- (-2, -1) -- (2, -1) -- (2, 0);
\draw[fill=black] (-2, -1) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2, -1) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (-1,0) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,0) circle(2pt);
draw[fill=black] (0, 2) circle(2pt);

\draw[blue,line width=2pt, smooth] plot coordinates 
{
%    (-4, -0.1)
    (-2, -1)
    (-1, 0)
    (0, 2)
    (1, 0)
    (2, -1)
%    (4, -0.1)
};

\draw[blue,line width=2pt,smooth] 
{(-4,-0.1)
(-4,-0.1)   ..controls(-3.6,-0.1) and (-2.9,-0.3)..
(-2.8,-0.5) ..controls(-2.5,-.9)  and (-2,-1)    ..
(-2,-1)

(2, -1)     ..controls(2.5,-0.9) and (2.8,-0.5) ..
(2.9,-0.3) ..controls(3.5,-0.1) and (4,-0.1) ..
(4,-0.1)
};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer. You have `\usepackage{pgfplots}` (as does OP), but without using it. Maybe use it, remove it, or write something about it.